# Spring boot soap web service. Why the outo-generated WSDL is wrong?

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I builded a simple spring boot Web service SOAP that get in request two ints and return sum.
Why, in the wsdl auto generated from xsd by spring maven plugin, at the `<wsdl:operation name="Add">` is missing `<wsdl:input>` ?

I don't know where to hit my head anymore.

Basically it looks like for some reason the response is being used instead of the request.

Configurations:
https://pastebin.com/aMhipJGL

Java classes:
https://pastebin.com/L20G5Czr

WSDL generated (wrong!)
https://pastebin.com/YU1kfb7X

this is the soapUI configuration (wrong!):

https://pasteboard.co/ZGFZIpvYCzVI.png

Thanks at all for the help.

Update:
I committed all project on github: https://github.com/neo7BF/calculatorws